# Jquery function into another function does not return all the results

Tags: jquery, function, append

I have a jQuery function that triggers another function, but it always returns the last result. What is the problem in my code? Thanks.

```js
function numbers(a, b) {
  res = '<div>' + a + ',' + b + '</div>';
}

function bloc1() {
  numbers(1, 2);
  numbers(3, 4);
  numbers(5, 6);
  $("#bloc1").append(res);
  // ouput : 5,6
  // but I want : 1,2 3,4 5,6
}

function bloc2() {
  numbers(10, 20);
  numbers(30, 40);
  $("#bloc2").append(res);
  // ouput : 30,40
  // but I want : 10,20 30,40
}

function bloc3() {
  numbers(500, 600);
  numbers(700, 800);
  $("#bloc3").append(res);
  // ouput : 700,800
  // but I want : 500,600 700,800   
}

bloc1();
bloc2();
bloc3();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call numbers it overwrites res and the append gets the last version of res and prints it to html.

Check out this fiddle it should answer your question:
https://jsfiddle.net/q4bjso0n/5/

Change your `numbers` function so that res is returned, not just set.

```
function numbers(a, b) {
  res = '<div>' + a + ',' + b + '</div>';
  return res;
}
```

or better

```
function numbers(a, b) {
  return '<div>' + a + ',' + b + '</div>';
}
```

Now the numbers function returns the value of res each time it is called.

You need to capture the values of the function numbers in a variable now and append THAT value to the html dom.

You could solve this in different ways e.g:

```
function bloc1() {
  //numbers(1, 2);
  //numbers(3, 4);
  //numbers(5, 6);
  $("#bloc1").append(""+numbers(1, 2)+numbers(3, 4)+numbers(5, 6));
  // ouput : 5,6
  // but I want : 1,2 3,4 5,6
}
```

or like this ...

```
function bloc1() {
  a = numbers(1, 2);
  b = numbers(3, 4);
  c = numbers(5, 6);
  $("#bloc1").append( ""+a+b+c);
  // ouput : 5,6
  // but I want : 1,2 3,4 5,6
}
```

or like this:

```
function bloc1() {
  myres = ""+numbers(1, 2)+ numbers(3, 4)+ numbers(5, 6);
  $("#bloc1").append(myres);
  // ouput : 5,6
  // but I want : 1,2 3,4 5,6
}
```

"res" lives in the function numbers. You need to check out functions and javascript variable scope.

Comment: Hi. It does not work. In your three propositions, the result is always "undefined" .... and I do not understand your last sentence: what should I do about my variables? "res" is in global variable, should I change that?Thanks.

Comment: I added a fiddle, you need to change your numbers function as well ... you are welcome, please accept my answer if it suits you.

Comment: Ah yes !... OK ! It works like a charm ! Many thanks for your fiddle and your answers.

Comment: You are welcome! I upvoted your question since it was well stated.